# What will be a valid sample xml for this schema using <any>

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

I received this schema from vendor and am trying to make heads or tails of it as to what can go inside it.

```
<schema targetNamespace="http://abc.com:9080/product/services/12WebService/types/" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
    <element name="Message">
        <complexType>
            <sequence>
                <any minOccurs="0"/>
            </sequence>
        </complexType>
    </element>
</schema>
```

What can I legally put inside `<types:Message>` element in below sample.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:types="http://abc.com:9080/product/services/12WebService/types/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <types:Message>
           <!-- What can go here -->
      </types:Message>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `message` you can put one arbitrary element - i.e. an element with any name in any namespace:

```
<Message xmlns="http://abc.com:9080/product/services/12WebService/types/">
  <something xmlns="some namespace" . . more attributes here . . .>
     . . . more sub-elements here . . 
  </something>
</Message>
```

An empty `message` is valid as well (due to `minOccurs="0"`):

```
<Message xmlns="http://abc.com:9080/product/services/12WebService/types/">
</Message>
```

What you cannot put inside `message` are multiple elements - this is invalid:

```
<Message xmlns="http://abc.com:9080/product/services/12WebService/types/">
  <something1 xmlns="some namespace">
  </something1>
  <something2 xmlns="some namespace">
  </something2>
</Message>
```

Note though that because the `processContents` attribute of `any` is not specified, it defaults to `strict` - that means that the validation **fails** if there is no schema for `some namespace` - or if the `something` element does not match that schema.

See documentation of `any` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256043.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for looking into this. However, I already tried what you suggested but it doesn't validate (using SoapUI to validate). `line 5: Element not allowed (strict wildcard, and no definition found): something@some namespace in element Message@http://abc.com:9080/product/services/12WebService/types/`

Comment: My bad - it is using `strict` mode by default, and so it fails if there is no schema for the `some namespace`. See updated answer above.

Comment: So, what are the ways to provide schema for `some namespace`? Is it part of `WSDL`? Or can I provide it as part of my client request? It'd be really helpful if you can explain with example. Thanks

Comment: When you validate a XML you provide to the validation software a set of schemas to be used....how this is done depends on the validation software being used. Adding the schema(s) in the WSDL could work...